# Put two arrays to Jtable rows

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jtable

I have two arrays, which is equal in terms of number of elements. I want to put it in a JTable rows (like in the ascii table example from bellow). I'm using table model and a loop for both arrays, but I archive something else (see print screen).
Note: I want to maintain the correspondence between elements of both arrays, like in the ascii table example.

```
                    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[stringArray.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
                    }

                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray)); //output [285, 715, 1437, 1749]


                    Integer[] intArray1 = new Integer[stringArray1.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray1.length; i++) {
                        intArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray1[i]);
                    }

                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray1)); //output [0, 0, 1087, 0]


                    DefaultTableModel modelPeaks = new DefaultTableModel();
                    JTable table = new JTable(modelPeaks);


                    modelPeaks.addColumn("1st Column");
                    modelPeaks.addColumn("2nd Column");


                    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < intArray1.length; j++) {

                            modelPeaks.addRow(new Object[]{intArray[i], intArray1[j]});
                        }
                    }
```

The output is:

[image]

But I want to archive this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
+   1st Column       +    2nd Column      +
+--------------------+--------------------+
+    285             +      0             +
+    715             +      0             +
+    1437            +     1087           +
+    1749            +      0             +
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I think that is from the loop, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Someone can help me? And thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: looks like as they haven't the same arrays.size() / lenght(), have to peak from both arrays concurrently and with test if loop isn't outof....

Comment: They have the same length() (see the output comments), but my mistake was that I used two loops. Correct me if I'm wrong or have misunderstood. Thanks for you interest Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last loop should read

```
 for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    modelPeaks.addRow(new Object[]{intArray[i], intArray1[i]});
 }
```

Always make sure that both array have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

If the arrays are both the same length you can use the same iterator for both:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    modelPeaks.addRow(new Object[]{intArray[i], intArray1[i]});
}
```